# SQL query to ActiveRecord Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have here my SQL Query and it rans on my phpmyadmin perfectly:

```
SELECT * FROM
  (
   SELECT requests.case_id AS case_id,
          requests.request_duration_to AS due,
          requests.request_to_id AS requests_to_id,
          requests.kind AS kind
   FROM requests AS requests
   WHERE `requests`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
   AND `requests`.`type` IN ('ConferenceHearingRequest')
   AND (`requests`.`request_duration_to` BETWEEN '2015-08-09 16:00:00' AND '2015-08-10 15:59:59')
   AND (requests.request_to_id = 1003 OR requests.created_by_id = 1003 OR requests.request_to_cc_ids LIKE '1003')
   ORDER BY created_at DESC
   ) AS requests
UNION
  (
  SELECT  records.case_id AS case_id,
          records.record_duration_to AS due,
          records.approve_to_id AS records_to_id,
          records.type_of_request AS kind
  FROM records AS records
  WHERE `records`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
  AND `records`.`type` IN ('ConferenceHearingRecord')
  AND (`records`.`record_duration_to` BETWEEN '2015-08-09 16:00:00' AND '2015-08-10 15:59:59')
  AND (records.approve_to_id = 1003 OR records.created_by_id = 1003 OR records.cc_to_ids LIKE '1003')
  ORDER BY created_at DESC
  )
```

My question is how can I make it to Rails way?

Comment: ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SQL query")

Comment: Thanks for the answer? But can you give me example how to do this? I'm a newbie so please forgive me.

Comment: This might help you to start, it's a beginners guide to ActiveRecord http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html

Comment: with great difficulty.

Answer (score 0):

You can write

`@result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("YOUR SQL QUERY WILL GO HERE")`

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch records in tow queries and `union` in ruby. ie.

```
requests = Request.select('requests.case_id AS case_id,
      requests.request_duration_to AS due,
      requests.request_to_id AS requests_to_id,
      requests.kind AS kind').where(" conditions ").order('created_at DESC')

records = Record.select(" records.case_id AS case_id,
      records.record_duration_to AS due,
      records.approve_to_id AS records_to_id,
      records.type_of_request AS kind ").where(" conditions ").order('created_at DESC')
```

And then union in ruby -

```
results = requests | records
```